# Unable to Call Constructor in Typescript Referencing Javascript Library

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm hitting a weird issue when trying to define declarations - where the constructor I've defined doesn't appear to be exist. Has anyone had a similar problem/know a good way to debug?

Error: crypto_1.SecretsStore is not a constructor

In the .d.ts file:

```
export type Environment = 'local' | 'dev' | 'staging' | 'production'

  export class SecretsStore {
    constructor(env: Environment, cacheFile?: string)
    isReady: () => boolean
    }
```

In the referenced dll:

index.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  SecretsStore
}
```

secret store file
    export default class SecretsStore {
      ...

```
  constructor(env: Environment, cacheFile?: ?string) {
    this.env = env
    ...
  }
}
```

In the code running it:

```
/// <reference path="./../declarations/crypto.d.ts"/>

import { SecretsStore } from '@.../crypto'
const secretStore = new SecretsStore(env.stage, undefined)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears there was a weird state when the library didn't update to have the expected constructor.